# IOS/objective-c: Create empty, non-nil date

Tags: ios, objective-c, null

I am using a dictionary to transmit data through JSON and am running into issue that dictionaries cannot have nil values which some form values have.  Can anyone suggest a good workaround?

FYI, I tried using @"" but this does not work for the NSDate type.

I could always do a complete hack like pick some characters such as %@!# to signify nil and then adjust on the server side but would like to avoid that.

Comment: If you don't have a value, don't add it to the dictionary at all.

Comment: I was using literal syntax.  I guess I can do this with if then testing for each variable before setting, but one non-mutable dictionary format seemed simpler if doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set nil value to NSDictionary directly, but if you want to set a value as `nil` in `NSDictionary`, you can use the `NSNull` class instead:

```
[yourDictionary setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"dateKey"];
```

Comment: Only do this if the key is required and the receiver can properly handle the null value.